# Conveniencia del SVG en Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Las formas que conozco de insertar un SVG son:

```
<img src="image.svg">
```

y con el SVG en linea (se puede manipular):

```
<svg class="image"> ... </svg>
```

Con esto me surgen ciertas dudas que buscando no logré despejar.

Mi pregunta es cuál es mas conveniente utilizar.
Entiendo que si no voy a editar el SVG uso la etiqueta `<img/>`.
Pero, en caso de tener que editarla, usaría la etiqueta `<svg>`.

El problema surge cuando el código es extenso o se usan muchas imagenes (el caso de un menú que podría tener 10 imagenes que irían variando según ciertos casos).
En ese caso no sé como resolverlo.

- ¿Tendría que tener en mi carpeta assets todos los svg con sus variantes?
- Recordando que estoy en Angular, ¿podría crear una carpeta de iconos con componentes donde solo esté el svg en linea?

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión seria poner los **SVG** en componentes separados y llamarlos con un nombre descriptivo por ejemplo el icono de “**bell**” o **campana** lo puedes llamar **iconNotification** o algo así la idea es que **no mezcles lógica con estáticos** y tu componente principal no se vea muy grande y así se pueda entender mejor